# LINUX : mount windows fractionated volume

Tags: linux, windows, mount, partition

I have on Windows VM two vmdk. I created a fractionated volume to see only one HDD.

[image]

I need to mount this in Linux.
I can see all sd**
But i can't make a mount, Linux does not know partition type. Can you help me?

Comment: What kind of volume is it exactly? There is no such thing as a "fractionated volume". Based on the purple color, it should be a spanned volume, so this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux

Comment: In "disposition" of my screenshot, you can see "fractionné" >> span in english yes. I will check your link.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider : It works, thank you very much. Topic closed.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it ... otherwise the question will stay as "unanswered" in the system forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks **@gerald Schneider**,

Solution is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux

I used **@Christian Hudon** solution which basically says to use `ldmtool` and walks you through the steps to configure on an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Since your partitions are NTFS formatted, your Linux distribution can't read it by default.
Depending on your distro, you have to check if a driver package for NTFS is available, the most common one would be `ntfs-3g`.

There's great documentation and the latest stable version here: https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/